# cannot debug node child process (using node native debugger)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-cluster, node-debugger

I'm trying to debug node child process, using native node debugger. See this [repo](https://github.com/yanivefraim/node-debug-childprocess) for example.

I tried all king of options, according to: [debug1](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/197), [debug1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840623/how-to-debug-node-js-child-forked-process), [debug3](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/130) (and a lot of other references I found online).

Non of those options worked for me..

This is my example code:

index.js:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const path = require('path');

const ls = spawn('node', [path.resolve('./child.js')], {execArgv: '--debug-brk=4545'});

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

child.js:

```
debugger;
const a = 123;

console.log(a);
```

I then run:

`node --debug-brk --inspect=9222 index.js`

And I open the `chrome-devtools://devtools/...` in chrome. Debugging the main process works great, and I see the child process output as well. Only thing that is not working is debug of child process...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question, just in case someone will have the same problem as I did. According to this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8690), the solution is:

```
const file = path.resolve('./child.js');
const args = ['--inspect=9228', '--debug-brk', file];
const ls = spawn('node', args);
```

You will have to open `chrome-devtools://devtools/...` with 9222 port + a new inspect window for child process, on port `9228` (as this is the port I added in this example)

You can see a working example [here](https://github.com/yanivefraim/node-debug-childprocess)