# Nodejs cpu profiling

Tags: node.js, linux, profiling

I need to debug 100% cpu usage of my nodejs process. I found `node --prof myapp.js` is very helpful. Now I have another application that will fork child process and I need to debug that child process. here is how I was forking the process.

```
require('child_process').fork("childfile.js", ["arg1","arg2], {silent: true});
```

Now my question is that, is it possible to profile child process, then how can I pass "--prof" option.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840623/how-to-debug-node-js-child-forked-process
possibly a duplicate of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require('child_process').fork("childfile.js", ["arg1","arg2], {silent: true,execArgv:["--prof"]});
```