# How do I Debug a Javascript Unit Test in Eclipse that is Run with Mocha?

Tags: node.js, eclipse, unit-testing, debugging, mocha.js

I am able to run my [Mocha/Unit.js](http://unitjs.com/guide/mocha.html) unit test with this command:

```
mocha fooTest.js
```

I want to set breakpoints in Eclipse and debug this unit test but I only see the following Debug Configuration options in Eclipse.

[image]

**Is there a way to execute Mocha unit tests in Eclipse's debug mode?**

I am using *Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Developers Oxygen Release (4.7.0)*. Maybe there is a plugin I can install or maybe create a node.js debug configuration and make it run with mocha? Or is there a way to do this in IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: Oxygen release is pretty old. You should upgrade to latest one (2020-06 as I'm writing), which comes with many improvements, including new plugin for JavaScript/TypeScript development.

Answer (score 1):

Its a two step process. I assume you have already placed the desired breakpoints on your JavaScript files (if you are using TypeScript, place the breakpoints in the compiled JavaScript files).

**Edit:** This works in newer versions of eclipse too.

1. Run your mocha tests

   1. Create a new  **External Tool Configuration**
   2. Set the *Location* to your `mocha.cmd` path. For example, if you installed mocha globally, this would be `path/to/node/mocha.cmd` (in Windows). If you installed locally, then it would be in your `node_modules`.
   3. Set the *Working Directory* to your projects path in the workspace. For example `${workspace_loc:/MyNodeProject}`
   4. In the *Arguments* provide the mocha suite path and Node's *inspector agent* (aka debug) flags: `inspect-brk`. The `inspect-brk` flag is important as it *Breaks before user code starts*, making your mocha tests to break/stop until you attach your debugger (step 2). For example `dist/tests/_suite.js --inspect-brk` (I am using TypeSCript so my tests are in the dist folder).
   5. Run your Configuration (click Run button).
   6. Your Eclipse console should show a message similar to this:

   ```
   Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/229a0421-cc41-4202-ab46-a392e86418e3
   For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
   ```
2. Start a Wild Web Developers inspector client.

   1. Create a new **Running Node.js Application** configuration under *Debug Configurations*. Menu: `Run -> Debug Configurations...`
   2. In the **Attach** tab set the *Address* and *Port* to the values printed in the console (from step one). In this case *Address*: 127.0.0.1 (equivalent to localhost), and *Port*: 9229. These are the default values, so if you have not changed your node/mocha configuration you should be using the same.
   3. Start the debug session (click Debug button)
   4. Your Eclipse should switch to the debug perspective and your test code start executing till the first break point.

After doing changes, since you already have the run configurations you just need to launch them (order is irrelevant as the inspector client debug config will run "indefinitely" waiting for a remote application connection).

### Issues with Node 10

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840623/how-to-debug-node-js-child-forked-process), there is a bug in node which causes the debugger to fail for child processes. Since mocha runs the tests in child processes, if you are using Node 10, you wont be able to debug your actual test code.